# Quartz.NET how to store fully qualified assembly name

Tags: c#, vb.net, scheduler, quartz.net

Quartz.NET is using the following for the job class name:

```
ClassName, myAssembly
```

However, myAssembly.dll lives in the GAC, and so I get the following error when trying to run the job:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'myAssembly' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I really need it to use the fully qualified name, so it will load from the GAC. E.g.

```
ClassName, myAssembly, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Is there any way I can tell Quartz.NET to use the full info? I noticed in 'GetStorableJobTypeName' in StdAdoDelegate.cs that the version number etc. are trimmed off the name.

Should I just create my own custom StdAdoDelegate and override that one function? Not really sure what best practice is here.

Comment: Why are you putting it in the GAC?

Comment: Because we have several hundred websites which share the same DLL, and it's easier to upgrade them all if the DLL is in the GAC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly want this, you should override the GetStorableJobTypeName as you have already discovered. I would strongly advice against storing the full name as this will lead to loads of problems. If nothing else, binding redirects whenever you create a new version of the DLL.

Comment: Apart from the DLL version changing, do you know what other kinds of problems we could expect to encounter? We actually need to be able to upgrade the DLL at times, so I won't be able to use a binding redirect. I think I need some way to make it robust against version changes, e.g. if the version changes (assembly fails to load), the job gets deleted.

Comment: OK so I came up with a bit of a workaround: I manually update the DLL reference in the JOB_CLASS_NAME column when the application starts, using a Regex pattern.